# How to set the DDWRT router to use only opendns?

Tags: router, wireless-router, dd-wrt, opendns

I need to setup my router to use opendns. It have the latest DDWRT firmware. But I want the router to act as a DNS server so it will cache the queries. I have set the Additional DNSMasq Options as follows :

```
no-resolv
strict-order
server=208.67.222.222
server=208.67.222.220
```

I have set the openDNS server for static dns servers and have added the following firewall rules to the router :

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i br0 -p udp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to $(nvram get lan_ipaddr)
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i br0 -p tcp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to $(nvram get lan_ipaddr)
```

According to this setup, Will the router forward all the dns requests to opendns without caching or will it cache?

Comment: Your router won't cache the dns requests but your computer will cache the dns information your router provides.

Comment: @Ramhound How to set the router to cache the requests?

Comment: Your question wasn't clear so I provided an incorrect answered.  **How did you come up with that command if you don't know what it does?**

Comment: @Ramhound Through the DDWRT wiki :) But there's no detailed explanation in there

Comment: OpenDNS is a poor choice as it will insert ads where there should have been an NX reply. This can sometimes cause software to malfunction. And ads are something you should avoid. Pick a better DNS provider. And besides, spoofing DNS is hardly a proper security measure, no matter what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the Services tab, under Additional DNSMasq Options, you can set these two options:

```
cache-size=0 
no-negcache
```

From the DNSMasq man page:

Cache-size:
Set the size of dnsmasq's cache. The default is 150 names. Setting the cache size to zero disables caching.

Comment: Hi, I need to enable caching and set it to first query opendns and then cache those requests

Comment: @EApubs - So instead of setting the size of the cache to 0 pick some other number?

Comment: Yes. The number indicates the number of names that will be cached.